# Record Exists error when duplicating records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm in the process of trying to duplicate a record and all of its subsequent child associations which are deeply nested. Below is a simplification of the problem.

I have the following `Foo` model:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :project,
  inverse_of::foos
  validates  :name,presence:true,uniqueness:{ scope: :project_id },
              format:{ with: /[0-9a-zA-Z\s\/_:\-.|]*/ }

end
```

I'm duplicating the `project` like this:

```
origin = Project.first
clone = origin.dup

clone.foos << clone_records(origin.foos)

clone.save

def clone_records(records)
  clones = []

  records.each do |record|
    cloned_record = record.dup
    cloned_record.project_id = nil
    cloned_record.name = "Copy of " + record.name

    # Which Generates:
    #<Foo:0x007f94353fc200> {
    #                    :id => nil,
    #                  :name => "Copy of Some Foo",
    #            :project_id => nil
    #
    # }


    clones.push(cloned_record)
  end

  return clones

end
```

The problem is, when I duplicate the `project` and assign the newly generated, renamed, `foos`, upon saving I get the error:

```
Foo Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "foos" WHERE ("foos"."name" = 'Copy of Some Foo' AND "foos"."project_id" = 1) LIMIT 1
```

However, no `foo` with that name exists:

```
Foo.where(name: "Copy of Some Foo")

# Foo Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "foos".* FROM "foos" WHERE "foos"."name" = $1  ORDER BY "foos"."id" ASC  [["name", "Copy of Some Foo"]]

# []
```

Can anyone tell me what might be going on here? I gather that it has something to do with the validation, but I don't understand why: 1) It thinks this new record exists, and 2) why the new record has a `project_id` set to the origin project when I've explicitly nullified that field.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `uniqueness: { scope: :project_id }` also applies to `nil` values. So if you have two records and they both have `project_id == nil` that would violate the uniqueness constraint.

Here is one way to allow nil values while still keeping the uniqueness constraint:

```
uniqueness: { scope: :project_id }, unless: Proc.new { |record| record.project_id.blank? }
```

When ActiveRecord complains that `Foo Exists`, it then rolls back the commit, so your cloned Foos do not persist to the database.

Answer (score 0):

First, this line:

```
Foo Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "foos" WHERE ("foos"."name" = 'Copy of Some Foo' AND "foos"."project_id" = 1) LIMIT 1
```

is not a error at all, it's just a log indicated Rails is running your uniqueness validation. And,

2) why the new record has a project_id set to the origin project when I've explicitly nullified that field.

Are you sure? it's project_id did set to the origin project? It's seems to me, the project_id is just set to the new created project's id.